# ANTLRv4 - How to identify unquoted quote within string

Tags: string, antlr, antlr4, apostrophe

How would I recognise the string "Aren't you a string?" without getting a token recognition error at the apostrophe?

Here is the relative grammar from my lexer:

```
STRING_LITERAL : '"' STRING? '"';
fragment STRING : STRING_CHARACTER+;  
fragment STRING_CHARACTER :  ~["'\\] | ESCSEQ;
fragment ESCSEQ : '\\' [tnfr"'\\];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the single quote from `~["'\\]`:

```
STRING_LITERAL : '"' STRING? '"';
fragment STRING : STRING_CHARACTER+;  
fragment STRING_CHARACTER :  ~["\\] | ESCSEQ;
fragment ESCSEQ : '\\' [tnfr"'\\];
```

Comment: Yes: otherwise you would need to escape it.